# IdentityServer4 Reject Token Request If Custom Parameter Not Valid

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have this test client sending RequestToken:

```
var tokenResponse = await client.RequestTokenAsync(new TokenRequest
            {
                Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
                GrantType = "password",
                ClientId = "My_Client",
                ClientSecret = "mysecret",
                Parameters =
                {
                    { "username", "user@entity.com" },
                    { "password", "userpassword" },
                    { "logged_entity_id", "143" },
                    { "scope", "MyAPI" }
                }
            });
```

Now each user has a list of entity and I want to reject the token request if the value in the parameter "logged_entity_id" does not exist in the user's list of entity.

I was initially planning on checking it via IsActiveSync in my CustomProfileService but I can't seem to access the raw parameters in IsActiveSync method.

```
    public class CustomProfileService : IProfileService
    {
        protected UserManager<User> _userManager;

        public CustomProfileService(UserManager<User> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("LoggedEntityId", context.ValidatedRequest.Raw["logged_entity_id"])
            };

            context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
        {
            var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject).Result;
            // var entityId = Can't access logged_entity_id parameter here

            context.IsActive = user != null && user.DeletingDate == null && user.entities.Contains(entityId);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
```

I'm not really sure if this is where I should check and reject it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In asp.net core you can  register a dependency using the built-in dependency injection container. The dependency injection container supplies the `IHttpContextAccessor` to any classes that declare it as a dependency in their constructors:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     ...
     services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
     ...
}
```

Then  in your class ,for example , in the implement of `IProfileService` :

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public CustomProfileService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{ 
     _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

Then in IsActiveAsync method get the value by :

```
var  id = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Form["logged_entity_id"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [ICustomTokenValidator](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/custom_token_request_validation.html) to validate token's request on your own way

> You can run custom code as part of the token issuance pipeline at the token endpoint. This allows e.g. for
>
> adding additional validation logic
>
> changing certain parameters (e.g.token lifetime) dynamically

```
public class CustomValidator : ICustomTokenRequestValidator 
{
    public Task<TokenValidationResult> ValidateAccessTokenAsync(TokenValidationResult result)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<TokenValidationResult> ValidateIdentityTokenAsync(TokenValidationResult result)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and in your startup.cs:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
  ...
})
.AddCustomTokenRequestValidator<CustomValidator>();
```

Comment: The .AddCustomTokenRequestValidator is looking for a class with ICustomTokenRequestValidator rather than the ICustomTokenValidator. There seems to be no AddCustomTokenValidator or I'm missing something.